# Apply conditional formatting depending on an other field's value

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, conditional-formatting, ms-access-2016

On the field  DaysSinceRequest of an an Access' Form, I am applying a conditional formatting depending on its value in eavch record, that part is fine.

But how could I tell "Apply the conditional formatting to the field DaysSinceRequest ONLY if the field DatePartReceived is empty/null" ?

Is there a way to do this ?

PS : Just to show that I've done something before haters start down rating, here are [the rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CExHa.png) I've applied to the field DaysSinceRequest and [the result in the Datasheet View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcHot.png)

Tell if if my post is not clear enough, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Expression Is` instead of `Field Value Is` and in Expression field you can use any expression, which evaluates to Boolean value. In your case you can use `IsNull` function